# grabbing current dom elements after keydown event

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to query a text area after a keydown event, however, the value from the dom seems to be before the keypress was evaluated. Here's the code:

```
Template.hello.events({
    'keydown ' : function(events) {
      console.log($('#data').val());
     }
});
```

in the "data" text area if I type in t, output is ""
then typing in e (after the t) the console says t
then typing in s the console says te
etc etc
events.keyCode is registering the right key, so theres no problem there but I need to grab dom elements after the event, but can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: How about keyup,may be keyup event gives u the result you want

Comment: yea, that worked. Thanks, forgot about the keyup event. can you post as answer so I close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyup event gives u the result u want